# How can I do to do many things in a tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have this button using React.js :

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-success btn-block"
 type="submit" onClick={props.onClose}  >
```

It works perfectly but I would like to do other things that only apply the onClose function. So I try that :

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-success btn-block"
 type="submit" onClick={closewindow()}  >
```

and I defined the function closewindow like that :

```
const  closewindow = () => {
      props.onClose
  }
```

But I got that : `Expression statement is not assignment or call`

Do you know how can I do to solve that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you check well and it is not a syntax error, onClick={closewindow()}  should be onClick={closewindow}, try and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

As @Anton said, you have to remove the `()` from the handler (`onClick={closewindow}`). You also have to add `()` to the function definition:

```
const closewindow = () => {
    props.onClose(); // () here (optional semicolon)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove `()` like this in onClick handler.

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-success btn-block"
 type="submit" onClick={closewindow}  >
```

Comment: the problem is there : `const  closemodal = () => {
      props.onClose
  }` I cannot let `props.onClose` like that ... :/

Comment: maybe it should be function call like props.onClose()